# Find number of arrays in an array which are not empty

Tags: ruby

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
[row1, row2, row3]
```

I need to find how many of those rows are not empty (have some object inside).  I know I can do row1.any?, but how would I find how many of those are in the array?

Answer (score 5):

Use the block form of [`Array#count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-count):

```
[row1, row2, row3].count &:any?
```

Comment: Beautiful solution! (given that's what he's asking for :-) )

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
[row1,row2,row3].select { |arr| arr.any? }.size
```

You [select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) just the objects (arrays) which have any elements, and then calculate the size of that resulting Array.

Answer (score 0):

And as usual, remember that `.any?` will not give you a hit if you array is filled with `false` or `nil`.

```
[[false], [nil], [true], []].count &:any? #=> 1 only one non-empty (true)
```

Perhaps it is better to do:

```
[[false], [nil], [true], []].reject(&:empty?).count #=> 3 non-empty (true, nil, false)
```